# How can I see files' permissions?

Tags: permissions, files

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit and I'm trying to understand how to see files' permisions and ownership.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terminal run

```
ls -l
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Righ-click a file `Properties → Permissions`.

Answer (score 5):

Via `stat`

```
stat file_name
```

or via `getfacl`

```
getfacl file_name
```

---

From man `getfacl`

```
For each file, getfacl displays the file name, owner, the group, and the Access
Control List (ACL). If a directory has a default ACL, getfacl also displays the
default ACL. Non-directories cannot have default ACLs.
```

From `man stat`

```
Display file or file system status.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. `stat` does exactly what the question is asking for, other ways to see files' / directories' permissions only show those incidentally.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to do

```
ls -l
```

Additionally to see hidden files as well

```
ls -al
```

One thing that I have in my `.bashrc` is

```
alias ll="ls -al"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get only the desired output i.e. the permissions and ownership info of a file you can use appropriate options of `stat`:

```
stat -c '%A %U:%G %n' file.txt
```

For example:

```
$ stat -c '%A %U:%G %n' file.txt
-rw-rw-r-- foobar:spamegg file.txt
```

With the `-c` or `--format` option of `stat`:

- `%A` will get us the permissions
- `%U` will get us the owner
- `%G` will give us owner group
- `%n` will give us the file name.

Answer (score 0):

As well as those ways, in the GUI, (Nautilus, Thunar or whatever), you can change the columns setting on the 'View' menu to include the permissions, as well as many other pieces of interest.